# apt-get update error in ubuntu utopic 14.10

Tags: updates, gwibber

help!!I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and then upgraded to 14.10 but when I perform `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal this error occurs.

how to fix this kind of error?

I already changed the default URI in the source.list to other site/mirror but always the same error.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
ryanjoseph@Satellite-L635:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script to automatically remove the non-existent ppas giving you 404 error.

```
    #!/bin/bash
sudo rm /tmp/update.txt; tput setaf 6; echo "Initializing.. Please Wait" 
sudo apt-get update >> /tmp/update.txt 2>&1; awk '( /W:/ && /launchpad/ && /404/ ) { print substr($5,26) }' /tmp/update.txt > /tmp/awk.txt; awk -F '/' '{ print $1"/"$2 }' /tmp/awk.txt > /tmp/awk1.txt; sort -u /tmp/awk1.txt > /tmp/awk2.txt
tput sgr0
if [ -s /tmp/awk2.txt ]
then
  tput setaf 1
  printf "PPA's going to be removed\n%s\n" "$(cat /tmp/awk2.txt)"
  tput sgr0
  while read -r line; do echo "sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:$line"; done < /tmp/awk2.txt > out
  bash out
else
  tput setaf 1
  echo "No PPA's to be removed"
  tput sgr0
fi
```

Copy and paste it in a text file , make this executable by running  `chmod +x filename` and execute `./filename`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot download the ppa files is because, well... they do not exist...

If you go to the ppa webpage in launchpad you can see that there are no builds available for your installation (utopic). The latest built file is from precise and although you cannot normally use this ppa you can mod the source.list file to spoof your ubuntu version.

Go to the source.list file and change the line

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu utopic main`

to `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu precise main`

and it should work as far as apt-get is concerned.

**Disclaimer: installing a package that is not directed for your installation is generally safe, HOWEVER you CAN break your system if the dependencies get messed up.** So while this is a possibly safe workaround, be careful on what you choose to install from old ppas (i.e. use common sense and do not install drivers)